# k-means and MiniBatchKMean in python is out of memory

Tags: python, memory-management, cluster-analysis, k-means, gensim

I am using sklearn.cluster "KMean" with python. I am trying to cluster data and plot graph for vectors(size =109977)
Here is my code:

```
model = gensim.models.Word2Vec.load("../wordvectors_300dimeansion.model")

vectors = model.syn0 #size 109977

n_clusters_kmeans = 20 # more for visualization 100 better for clustering
#kmeans = KMeans(init='k-means++', n_clusters=n_clusters_kmeans, n_init=10)
min_kmeans = MiniBatchKMeans(init='k-means++',    n_clusters=n_clusters_kmeans, n_init=10)

min_kmeans.fit(vectors)

X_reduced = TruncatedSVD(n_components=50,   random_state=0).fit_transform(vectors)
X_embedded = TSNE(n_components=2, perplexity=40, verbose=2).fit_transform(X_reduced)


target = min_kmeans.labels_
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))
ax = plt.axes(frameon=False)
plt.setp(ax, xticks=(), yticks=())
plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.0, bottom=0.0, right=1.0, top=0.9, wspace=0.0, hspace=0.0)
plt.scatter(X_embedded[:, 0], X_embedded[:, 1], c=target, marker="x")
plt.show()
```

kMean computing pairwise distance means to create a matrix with pairwise distances of 109977X109977

And I think due to this I got "out of memory" error.

pl. suggest me some scalable k-means clustering algorithm for large dataset.

Is there any tool available for this purpose? which I can import in my program directly as I did for sklearn.cluster "KMean" and "MiniBatchKMean", so that I can directly import it in my program.

Thanks.

Comment: What's the dimensions of your training samples. I think the high dimensions is the main reason for the out of memory. You can try to make your vectors as scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.

Comment: @Bosco Tsang, thanks for the reply.  vectors has 300 dimensions.

Comment: I have try a dataset with 200000 * 500 on my desktop with 8G Ram and it went well.

Comment: K-means does *not* compute a pairwise distance matrix. Because it ever only computes squared deviations of a point to a *center*, and not point-to-point.